# Excel automatically formatting to decimal point, need short integer

Tags: conditional-formatting

How do I save a number as an integer and not as a decimal?

I am trying to load data from an Excel table into an Oracle database table Oracle wants a short integer but Win10 Excel refuses to reformat the column from a decimal point to the '0' format in Custom formatting. It keeps giving me a Double format.

This is very frustrating as it is a simple process that is not working.

Comment: Have you tried round(your calculation,0)

Answer (score 2):

Formatting does not change the value. Round the number or use the Int() function to cut off decimals.